# Random forest: Should OOB accuracy equals Test Set accuracy?

Tags: r, random-forest, accuracy

In random forests, we bootstrap a sample from the training set, and train a decision tree on the bootstrapped sample. Some observations are not drawn from the training set, and not used to train the decision tree: these are out-of-bag (OOB) observations that we can use to compute the performances of the model.

For random forests, I thought that the out-of-bag performance should be the same (or at least very similar) to the performance calculated on a separated
test set.

But this does not seem to be the case.

In the following R code, the accuracy computed on the out-of-bag sample is 77.81%, while the one computed on a separated test set is 81%.

What I am doing wrong?

```r
library(randomForest)
library(ISLR)

Carseats$High <- ifelse(Carseats$Sales<=8,"No","Yes")
Carseats$High <- as.factor(Carseats$High)

train = sample(1:nrow(Carseats), 200)

rf = randomForest(High~.-Sales,
                  data=Carseats,
                  subset=train,
                  mtry=6,
                  importance=T)

acc <- (rf$confusion[1,1] + rf$confusion[2,2]) / sum(rf$confusion)
print(paste0("Accuracy OOB: ", round(acc*100,2), "%"))

yhat <- predict(rf, newdata=Carseats[-train,])
y <- Carseats[-train,]$High
conftest <- table(y, yhat)
acctest <- (conftest[1,1] + conftest[2,2]) / sum(conftest)
print(paste0("Accuracy test set: ", round(acctest*100,2), "%"))
```

Comment: You are not *necessarily* doing something wrong (have not checked your code); your premise is false - there is no reason whatsoever that the accuracies on these 2 different sets should be equal (or even close). On the other hand, one could very well argue here that the two values of 81% and 78% *are* indeed "close".

Comment: @desertnaut well, the OOB accuracy should be calculated on observations the algorithm did *not* use for training, and the test set accuracy is also calculated on observations the algorithm did *not* use from training. Both comes from the same distribution (it's the same "starting" training set). So I expected the result to be the same

Comment: The fact that data (training, test, whatever) themselves come from the same distribution is itself an assumption; it should not be taken for granted in *real* datasets. Plus, I don't have a reference right now, but I remember arguments (papers, maybe?) advising against using OOB data for performance assessment.